# Puppet: Copy folder recursively - preserving mode?

Tags: puppet

With puppet I realize I can copy folders recursively and set permissions on individual files recursively. But I have a source folder with (many, many) files each with carefully configured permissions. How do I do the puppet equivalent of:

```
cp -a $source $dest
```

?

This:

```
file { '/some/dest':
    ensure => directory,
    source => "/some/src",
    recurse => true,
}
```

Does *not* preserve mode.

Also, [Best Practices: Recursive File Resources](https://github.com/puppetlabs/best-practices/blob/master/recursive-file-resources.md) says to only use recursive files:

> When the total number of recursive files to manage is small (such as ten or fewer)

Ok, so for the sake of argument, lets say `/some/src` has 1000s of files with complicated modes.

According to that link, my other options are

- [recursive_file_permissions defined type](https://forge.puppet.com/npwalker/recursive_file_permissions). Here I can only set all files to the same permissions, not set them to have the same permissions as the source == won't work for us.
- [puppet/archive module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/archive)
- build a package for the files, and use a Package resource to manage it.

Both of the two last approaches seem to involve an awful lot of work to achieve `cp -a $source $dest`. Unless puppet has primitives to create an archive or debian package from `$source` - I'm thinking not...

So: Is it really not possible to `cp -a $source $dest` using puppet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`source_permissions`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions) attribute that controls what happens when copy files without explicitly setting the mode which might do what you want. You should set it to either `use` or `use_when_creating`.